# Elastic Beanstalk Instance keeps deleting Clamscan

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using clamscan to check content on my elastic beanstalk instance, however, I'm having an issue where AWS either moves the instance to another IP and then clam scan is suddenly uninstalled. Is there a good way to prevent this from happening?

Thanks.

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If AWS is *"moving the instance to a new IP"* what is actually happening is that Elastic Beanstalk is deleting your instance and spinning up an entirely new instance. I assume you manually configured ClamAV on your EB EC2 instance via SSH, which is the wrong way to configure EB instances. You even get a warning on the screen when you SSH into the instance telling you not to make any changes to the server because they won't be persisted across EB instances.

You have to use the appropriate methods provided by Elastic Beanstalk to configure your instances so that Elastic Beanstalk knows how to configure new instances when it automatically creates them for you. The method for doing this is [documented here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html).